# change extjs 4 color theme to something else

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

how do I change the default theme of extjs 4.

For example I do not want use to color blue.

I want it to default it to some other color of my choice?
I dont know how to override the css to do that.
any help would be appreciated.

Is there a tutorial where I install new themes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the theming guide, it covers pretty much all you need: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/theming

Comment: @Evan..It works great.. the only problem is IE 9.0 is showing a very very lighter shade of color as compared to other browsers. Is there a fix for that

Answer (score 0):

You can try override base theme:

```
this.columnChart.on('afterrender', function() {
         var colors = ['#1486fb','#fbe500','#00b300','#1486fb','#999']; 
        var baseColor = '#eee'; 
        Ext.define('Ext.chart.theme.Fancy', {
            extend: 'Ext.chart.theme.Base', 
            constructor: function(config) {
                this.callParent([Ext.apply({           
                    colors: colors
                }, config)]);
            }
        });
```

and use simply